# Create Azure pipelines from scripts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was playing with Azure Build pipelines. My Goal was that Developer should be able to create a Build Pipeline for their project. But he/she will not be creating it via Azure DevOps console, instead, they would Trigger a build job which would create Build pipelines for them.  I was able to achieve it by having a common Template.json and invoking it using PowerShell scripts.

But I see that we can create a build pipeline by having an azure-pipelines.yaml  in our repo. So I have two issues which I am struggling to face.

1. An Azure pipeline job that will read the azure-pipelines.yaml and create a build pipeline for the user.
2. Read the `Azure-pipelines.yaml` file which is kept inside the sub directories in the repo.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: What about having a basic git repo for an application (or a repo for each type of app) where you could have a basic azure-pipelines.yaml?

Comment: @LiviuCostea yes . That solves the issue . But our hands are tied.  We cannot change the repo structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved :)

1. Created a powershell script which uses the json file which was exported from a existing pipeline job.
2. The JSON file will be using the azure-pipelines.yml file to create the tasks.
3. The Powershell script updates the json file and makes a rest call to create a pipeline.

The documentation is very poor . I was unable to find documentation on creation of pipeline through code . I Checked the Request body while saving the pipeline from which I was able to get the details to refer the yml file .

Comment: Really nice solution @bkr. Jenkins offers really good DSL to create pipelines in code. I am planning to do something very similar in our organisation. Is this solution that you have open-source by any chance. If it is, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/1.0.55) to Get-APBuildDefinition and Publish-APBuildDefinition.

The functions use return and post json objects. I modify the json templates with tokens and update them are needed. Format-APTemplate will replace the tokens in the json template.

There are functions for release pipelines as well; Get-APReleaseDefinition and Publish-APReleaseDefinition.

Comment: Hi, do you know any documentation regarding this? I'm gonna use a script/template to implement Build and Deploy on AzureDevOps. There is no good info related to this on Azure doc.

Comment: AzurePipelinesPS is a powershell module I wrote to wraps the AzureDevops API. The github page has information on how to create a session and all of the api endpoints are documented in the Microsoft docs. What are you stuck on?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I made it to work using this command: $ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u myusername:mytoken -d @build.json https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myrepo/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1